# I'm having trouble comparing a character against input. Specifically a character in a string to "\"

Tags: c++, eclipse, character

I'm trying to write a simple calculator and am having trouble with this snippet of code.

```
    if(Input[i] == '+' || Input[i] == '-' || Input[i] == '*' 
          || Input[i] == '/' || Input[i] == '\' || Input[i] == '%')
```

Basically when I write this I get a compiler error that says "bad character sequence encountered". My eclipse IDE changes the  color of the text on screen to blue to indicate that everything after

```
   Input[i] == '\'
```

is also encased in '  ' markings.
How do I make it so that "\" is what Input[i] is being compared against?

Comment: You can see what I'm talking about at the end of my if statement. Notice how the text changes colors.

Answer (score 2):

\ is a escape character that needs to be escaped
'\\' should be valid

Comment: Thanks for helping a newbie out :^)

Answer (score 0):

Okay look at this way if you want to print % , you should use `printf("%%");` instead of `printf("%")` only since when compiler sees single % then it expect that something like `%d` or `%f` or.... is coming but if we only want % to be printed we should use `%%` , thats all.
Okay if problem still persist try to use ASCII value instead of `Input[i] == '\'` you should use `Input[i] == 92` I guess ASCII value of '\' is 92 . 
Hope this will help.
Cheers!!